# jqGrid error when data is null

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller, jqgrid, jqgrid-formatter, mvcjqgrid

I'm using a jqGrid to display data, where some fields may be null in the database. With the nulls present, I get the error, *Object reference not set to an instance of an object.*

I've added code to change null to string as below, but the jqGrid is not being displayed:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#list').jqGrid({
            caption: "MM",
            url: '@Url.Action("GetAll", "Grid")',
            datatype: 'json',
            jsonReader: {
                root: "Rows",
                page: "Page",
                total: "Total",
                records: "Records",
                repeatitems: true,
                id: "Id",
                cell: "RowCells"
            },
            mtype: 'POST',
            colNames: ['Serial'],
            colModel: [
                {
                    name: 'Serial', index: 'Serial', align: 'center', width: 60, formatter: nullformatter
                }
            ],
            pager: $('#pager'),
            rowNum: 10,
            rowList: [10, 20, 50, 100],
            sortname: 'Id',
            sortorder: 'desc',
            viewrecords: true,
            altRows: true,
            shrinkToFit: false,
            width: '1041',
            height: 'auto',
            hidegrid: false,
            direction: "rtl",
            gridview: true,
            rownumbers: true,
            footerrow: true,
            loadComplete: function () {
                $("tr.jqgrow:odd").css("background", "#E0E0E0");
            },
            loadError: function (xhr, st, err) {
                jQuery("#rsperror").html("Type: " + st + "; Response: " + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
            }
        })
          var nullformatter = function (cellvalue, options, rowobject) {
              alert('cell value==>>' + cellvalue);
              if (cellvalue == undefined || isnull(cellvalue) || cellvalue == 'NULL' || cellvalue.trim().length == 0) {
                  cellvalue = ' ';
              }
              return cellvalue;
          };
    })
</script>
```

Comment: probably the reason is the usage of `isnull` function? There are no standard JavaScript function `isnull`. Do you defined it in some way? You should try to remove the part `|| isnull(cellvalue)` or just replace the body to `return cellvalue == null || cellvalue === "NULL" ? "" : cellvalue;` The test `cellvalue == null` is the same as `cellvalue === null || cellvalue === undefined`.

Comment: @Oleg I use it but don't work

Comment: @Oleg my function don't call by formatter.

Comment: Do you mind that `nullformatter` will be never called? Probably you defined `nullformatter` in the wrong scope? Do you started your code in the debugger? You need just press F12 to start developer tools and then start debugging, on error you will see where exactly the error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" take place.

Comment: You can try to use anonymous function `{name: 'Version',..., formatter: function (cellvalue) { return cellvalue == null || cellvalue === "NULL" ? "" : cellvalue; }}`

Comment: @Oleg I use this but error fro value null "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Comment: I'm sure that we speak about *different things*. Could you provides the demo which reproduces the problem? You can get any jsfiddle demo (like http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/o6g9rnug/), modify it to demonstrates your problem, click on "Update" to save it and to post the URL to modified demo.

Comment: @Oleg  You'r right. I mistake, but when i use anonymous function, same error show.

Comment: @Oleg http://jsfiddle.net/o6g9rnug/9/

Comment: @Oleg please see above link. when amount is null don't show jqgrid

Comment: It do display the grid in my tests, but you have **absolutely wrong `colModel`**. You define two columns with **the same** `name: 'amount'`. The `name` values have to be different. Nevertheless your custom formatter  works correctly, but processing the same `null` data works not so good in the second column `name: 'amount', formatter: "number"`. It's problem of wrong data for the ` formatter: "number"`. Do you looked at the demo http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/u9x2fcz1/6/ which I posted you before?

Answer (score 0):

Can you add below condition,. its works for me.

```
var nullformatter = function (cellvalue, options, rowobject) {
            if (cellvalue == undefined || isnull(cellvalue) || cellvalue == 'NULL' || cellvalue.trim().length==0)
            { 
              cellvalue = ' '; 
            } 
          return cellvalue;
        }
```

If above condition not work to alert the cell value.

```
alert('cell value==>>'+cellvalue);
```

After that you will correct it.

or try follow condition

```
if(null!=cellvalue && cellvalue.length>0){
   return cellvalue;
}else{
        return " ";
 }
```

Comment: where do I use alert?

Comment: before if statement...suppose its shows object to.... use follow alert(JSON.stringify(cellvalue));

Comment: alert('cell value==>>'+JSON.stringify(cellvalue));

Comment: Don't show alert. alert('cell value==>>'+JSON.stringify(cellvalue));

Comment: I use alert before if statement but don't show alert

Comment: nullformatter  code add once finished the jqgrid base code.

Comment: Please refer @Oleg example http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/BackgroundColorFormatter.htm .....

Answer (score 0):

If you use `var nullformatter = function (cellvalue, options, rowobject) {...}` syntax then you have to move the definition of `nullformatter` **before** the usage (before you crate the grid with `$('#list').jqGrid({...});`). You current code use `formatter: undefined`. Only if you would use `function nullformatter (cellvalue, options, rowobject) {...}` then you can define the function below of the usage.

Comment: @mahdisdezfouli: Look at the demo http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/u9x2fcz1/6/ it uses your code and some test data. It loads the data correctly. I don't see any problem. You should compare it with your code and your data returned from the server. (the demo use JSFiddle echo service which allows to simulate JSON responses from the server)

Comment: sorry this error maybe bout NULL . because in db, there is NULL. and in demo when i chang (null to NULL) this not show.

Comment: @mahdisdezfouli: You are welcome! I recommend you to use [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to make HTTP trace or at least Developer Tools of IE/Chrome/Firefox (press F12 to start). If you will see full communication between the server and jqGrid you will be sure solve the problem or at least to include JSON which the server in the demo http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/u9x2fcz1/6/ which I posted you. I personally use Fiddler very frequently.

Comment: @mahdisdezfouli: You are welcome! Please inform you after you will find the reason or after you will have JSON response from the server which reproduces the problem.

Comment: Sorry. when i use demo:  jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/u9x2fcz1/6  and changed (null to NULL ) it doesn't work. when i used capital it's wrong. why? please help me.

Comment: @mahdisdezfouli: Sorry, but I can't follow you. The demo http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/u9x2fcz1/6/ have already both `["NULL"]` and `[null]` as input data and both will be displayed as empty strings. Where you  see a problem? **JavaScript is case sensitive.** So there are only one `null` which will be interpreted as the possible value of `Object`. `Null` or `NULL` without `""` is the name of variable in initializer and absolutely wrong in JSON input.

Comment: value of data is NULL in sql and i cann't changed to null because it's a "long". when data is empty in sql, it is NULL. I really don't know where is problem.

Comment: @mahdisdezfouli: Sorry, but what you write is wrong. You get data first in your backend code. The reading of data looks typically something like `string feedbackSummary = dr.IsDBNull(2) ? null : dr.GetString(2);` (if you use `SqlDataReader dr` and you read from the 3-d field of the Query results). So you fill C# `null` in for nullable datatype (the variable `feedbackSummary` in my example): string, `int?` and so on. If your MVC code return nullable data then `null` will be placed. Alternatively you can change `null` to `"NULL"` string during returning of data. I do the same permanently.

Comment: Thanks for reply. your'r right, i get null in my db but show same error. i try it again. Thank you very much

Comment: @mahdisdezfouli: You are welcome! I recommend you to use [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) or Developer Tools of IE/Chrome/Firebug to make HTTP trace of communication between the server and jqGrid. Having exact JSON data from the server response you will quickly find the reson.